# Range join without duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that contains only datetimes, like so:

```
           datetime
2016-05-16 10:00:00
2016-05-16 10:30:00
2016-05-16 11:00:00
2016-05-16 11:30:00
2016-05-16 12:00:00
2016-05-16 12:30:00
2016-05-16 13:00:00
2016-05-16 13:30:00
2016-05-16 14:00:00
2016-05-16 14:30:00
2016-05-16 15:00:00
2016-05-16 15:30:00
2016-05-16 16:00:00
2016-05-16 16:30:00
2016-05-16 17:00:00
2016-05-16 17:30:00
2016-05-16 18:00:00
2016-05-16 18:30:00
2016-05-16 19:00:00
2016-05-16 19:30:00
```

I want to range join this table against a table that tags certain time intervals as `closed`:

```
              start                stop closed
2016-05-04 16:56:07 2016-05-04 17:26:20   TRUE
2016-05-13 09:29:23 2016-05-14 21:27:17   TRUE
2016-05-14 21:00:39 2016-05-15 20:48:37   TRUE
2016-05-16 10:26:56 2016-05-16 11:48:24   TRUE
2016-05-16 11:33:42 2016-05-16 12:24:31   TRUE
2016-05-16 13:08:15 2016-05-16 14:27:42   TRUE
2016-05-16 15:46:07 2016-05-16 16:19:38   TRUE
2016-05-16 16:33:49 2016-05-16 17:52:31   TRUE
2016-05-16 16:34:12 2016-05-16 17:52:50   TRUE
2016-05-16 16:35:00 2016-05-16 17:53:33   TRUE
```

As you can see, some of these intervals overlap and so when I range join the two tables with

```
SELECT d.*, c.closed 
FROM dates d 
LEFT JOIN closures c
ON c.start <= d.datetime AND d.datetime <= c.stop
```

I get duplicate rows in the resulting table. Is there any way of tagging the datetimes in the left table as closed if at least one interval straddles it without duplicating any rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS()` that does exactly what you asked for :

```
SELECT d.*,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM closures c
                        WHERE c.start <= d.datetime AND d.datetime <= c.stop)
            THEN 'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE'
       END as Your_Ind
FROM dates d
```

Or just use `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*, c.closed 
FROM dates d 
LEFT JOIN closures c
ON c.start <= d.datetime AND d.datetime <= c.stop
```

If you are intrested only in the records that are closed, then use `EXISTS()` on the `WHERE` clause.

```
 SELECT d.*,'TRUE'
FROM dates d
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM closures c
             WHERE c.start <= d.datetime AND d.datetime <= c.stop)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select d.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from closed c
                          where c.start <= d.datetime AND d.datetime <= c.stop and
                                d.closed = TRUE
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as closed
from dates;
```

This should be faster than a version that uses `group by` or `select`distinct`, particularly with an index on`closed(start, stop, closed)`.